# NHibernate just-in-time SQL for linq criteria on bag collections

Tags: linq, nhibernate

In NHibernate is it possible to filter a collection property which is mapped as a bag association such that when the lazy loading occurs the filter is applied directly in the SQL rather than loading the whole bag collection and then filtering it?

F.Y.I - I'm using xml mapping files.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you define the filter in the mappings: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#filters

Comment: OK, I was just wondering if there was a work around to do a Linq IQueryable style approach where its not based on the mapping.  Thanks.

Comment: That's why I do like SO. This was unknown for me. Nice one!