# Is it possible to use NHibernate Filters to filter through references?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Contrived example, but let's say I have a these entities:

```
public class Root
{
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public virtual CustomerData Data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerData
{
    public virtual string FooName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say I want to create a filter for Root based on the value of FooName. Intuitively, I tried this in my FooMap class. Using Fluent mappings.

```
ApplyFilter("FooNameFilter", "Customer.Data.FooName in (:argument)");
```

This doesn't work. A SqlClient.SqlException is thrown stating `The multi-part identifier "Customer.Data.FooName" could not be bound.`

Is there a way to make filters work this way, or am I forced to move that logic into all `Query<Root>()`s instead?

Comment: My bets are on having to move the logic into your queries.  As I understand it, filters are SQL, not HQL, so you wouldn't be able to use that intuitive `Customer.Data.FooName` joining syntax.  I think the filters have to just be about columns that are defined on that one table.

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of. Doesn't screw me, but I really liked the filter API for what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What could be working, is to move the `filter` to the `CustomerData` object if possible, or to create "more sophisticated SQL condition" applied on the `Customer` mapping. But it is about pure SQL, no references. How do the filters work?

The `filters` are the same as the `where` clause, but could be adjusted in a runtime. The extract from documentation [18.1. NHibernate filters](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters)

> NHibernate adds the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach
>   those filters at both a class and a collection level. **A filter
>   criteria is the ability to define a restriction clause very similiar
>   to the existing "where" attribute available on the class and various
>   collection elements**. Except these filter conditions can be
>   parameterized. The application can then make the decision at runtime
>   whether given filters should be enabled and what their parameter
>   values should be. Filters can be used like database views, but
>   parameterized inside the application.

The definition of the `where`:

> where (optional) specify an arbitrary SQL WHERE condition to be used when retrieving objects of this class

Other words, these settings act as "add on" to our mapping. They are extending it (both `where` and `filter`) with more *SQL balast*. The filter could be shared among many mappings and applied to all queries inside one session, but it must target the column:

```
condition=":myFilterParam = MY_FILTERED_COLUMN"
```

Comment: Given the error message, that's what I figured was happening under the covers. What I'm still not sure about is if I can make this work with filters. I'm not sure how filtering CustomerData helps when I want to filter queries against Root. I'm pretty new to NHibernate, so I'm not sure what all of my options are yet.

Comment: The essence of a Filter is mostly in the collection handling. You can have large collection, or dependent on a culture, user name etc. In these cases, it could be OK to use filter. You find out what is the restriction for current session (user culture) and you can set that to a session. All collections will be filtered with this setting. But in case, that you'd like to get a Customer, which has some setting... use Criteria or QueryOver api. You will "Join" the customer data and apply filter during querying

Comment: There are some links to this topic, when I tried to explain how to use filter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17109300/1679310, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14378253/1679310

Comment: Sounds like I'm misusing them then. Thanks!

Comment: Good if this could help anyhow ;)