# How to add a default WHERE condition to NHibernate queries for a certain type

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I'd like all queries that query a certain type, to include a where statement by default.

More exactly, I have an interface IIsTenantSpecific, with a property TenantId - so the entities belong to a single tenant.

When I query a type implenting this interface, then NHIberante should always add a WHERE clause, filtering the TenantId.

Is there a mechanism (like interceptor, or event listener) in NHibernate that allows this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, that this scenario could be easily covered by built in feature:

#### [18.1. NHibernate filters](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters)

Similar [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31592194/1679310)

A cite from the *doc*:

> NHibernate adds the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach
>   those filters at both a class and a collection level. A filter
>   criteria is the ability to define a restriction clause very similiar
>   to the existing "where" attribute available on the class and various
>   collection elements. Except these filter conditions can be
>   parameterized. The application can then make the decision at runtime
>   whether given filters should be enabled and what their parameter
>   values should be. Filters can be used like database views, but
>   parameterized inside the application.
>
> In order to use filters, they must first be defined and then attached
>   to the appropriate mapping elements. To define a filter, use the
>   `<filter-def/>` element within a `<hibernate-mapping/>` element:
>
> ```
> <filter-def name="myFilter">
>     <filter-param name="myFilterParam" type="String"/>
> </filter-def>
> ```
>
> Then, this filter can be attached to a class:
>
> ```
> <class name="MyClass" ...>
>     ...
>     <filter name="myFilter" condition=":myFilterParam = MY_FILTERED_COLUMN"/>
> </class>
> ```
>
> or, to a collection:
>
> ```
> <set ...>
>     <filter name="myFilter" condition=":myFilterParam = MY_FILTERED_COLUMN"/>
> </set>
> ```

So, once we define a filter, and apply it on our collections - we can later easily at any time turn that filter on on a whole session:

```
session.EnableFilter("myFilter").SetParameter("myFilterParam", "some-value");
```

And from that moment, each collection is filtered with passed "some-value" over selected column